# Problem adding datefield to invoice odoo12

Tags: invoice, datefield, odoo-12

The following Python script does not create a date field:

```
from datetime import datetime

from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError


class DealInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    x_date_deal = fields.Date(string='Date Deal',
                                required=True,
                                readonly=True,
                                default=(date.today()),
                                index=True,
                                states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'sent': [('readonly', False)]},
                                help='Item date deal.')


    @api.constrains('x_date_deal')
    def _x_date_deal_check(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.x_date_deal and record.x_date_deal [0] <= str(date.today()):
                raise ValidationError(_("Date deal must be before current date."))
```

Comment: If by the field has not been created you mean that the field `x_date_deal` does not exist on the table `account_invoice` in the database, check your `__init__.py` files to make sure your file is being imported, then restart Odoo and upgrade the module.

Comment: If you mean that you don't see the newly-created field on your view, that's because you need to modify it using inheritance.

Comment: solved a different way via:

Comment: from odoo import api, fields, models

class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    x_date_deal = fields.Date(string="Date of Deal")

Comment: I've just seen the `readonly=True` option. Using it will make Odoo ignore whatever the user puts there. It's meant to be used along with a `_compute`

Comment: thanks, that's something I should have seen myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code hereunder gives the error 'date not defined'. In the end i just want avalidation that a date is today or not more than 5 days in the past. Thanks for your help.

> from odoo import api, fields, models, _ 
>   from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError 
>   from datetime import date 
>   today = date.today
>
> class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
>       _inherit = 'account.invoice'
>       _name = 'account.invoice'
>
> ```
> x_date_deal = fields.Date(string='Date of Deal', required=True, readonly=False, index=True,
>                                 states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'sent': [('readonly', False)]},
>                                 help='Date of Deal')
>
> @api.constrains('x_date_deal')
> def _delivery_date_check(self):
>     for record in self:
>         if record.x_date_deal and record.x_date_deal > today:
>             raise ValidationError(_("Deal Date must be ...."))
> ```